# Rank of Elliptic Curve over Finite Field

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, cryptography

In the paper titled: "[The Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.472.9475&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" by Don Johnson and Alfred Menezes, there is a statement in section 4.3 "Basic Facts":

> $ E(F_q) $ is an abelian group of rank 1 or 2. That is: $ E(F_q) $ is
>   isomorphic to $ Z_{n_1} \times Z_{n_2} $ where $ n_2 $ divides $ n_1 $
>   for unique positive integers $ n_1 $ and $ n_2 $.

Is there an easy proof of why this is so? My current understanding is that for cryptography we try to find a subgroup of $ E(F_q) $ that has prime order (while avoiding singular ones whose order is $ q $ itself). I thought that the order of $ E(F_q) $ could be a composite number with more than 2 factors. Thus I feel surprised by the statement that $ E(F_q) $ has rank 1 or 2.

I am probably missing a lot of things; perhaps having more than 2 factors has nothing to do with rank. But then why is there such a tight bound on the rank, etc.

**Update:** The same quoted paragraph adds this further statement which I find hard to see why/how:

> Moreover, $ n_2 $ divides $ q - 1 $.

Comment: Also $n_2\mid n_1$ (to get uniqueness we need $n_1,n_2$ to be the invariant factors). Yes, in crypto they often prefer curves with $n_2=1$. This is because then they can use the "full" group, because it is cyclic and fit for DLP. The divisibility $n_2\mid q-1$ follows from the fact that the Weil pairing on $E(\Bbb{F}_q)$ takes values that are roots of unity of order dividing $q-1$. Because $E(\Bbb{F}_q)$ contains the full $n_2$-torsion of $E(\overline{\Bbb{F}_q})$ the pairing values contain all the roots of unity of order $n_2$.

Comment: May be there is a simpler proof of $n_2\mid q-1$? I don't know this stuff too well :-(

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen. My central question is why just two factors $n_1$ and $n_2$? Why not $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$? And why can't $E(F_q)$ be isomorphic to $Z_{n_1} \times Z_{n_2} \times Z_{n_3}$? Why does it stop at $n_2$?

Comment: because the multiplication by $n$ map has degree $n^2$, so to find $n$-torsion points you "sort of" have to solve a degree $n^2$ "equation", that has at most $n^2$ solutions. If there were a nontrivial $n_3$ that would mean you have found $n_3^3$ points of order dividing $n_3$ and that's larger than $n_3^2$, so it's impossible.

Comment: Also, I think $n_2$ is in fact the gcd of $n_1$ and $q-1$

Comment: @mercio: That's definitely not true (that $n_2 = \gcd(n_1, q-1)$). For example, $X_0(11)(\mathbf{F}_7) \cong \mathbf{Z}/10\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: hmm yeah you're right that statement is way too strong. Thank you for correcting me.